# How to populate bootstrap multi select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using two multiselect dropdown. second multiselect option is depends on first multiselect values.

I am trying to fill the second multiselect (#field_zone)  option using ajax call when first dropdown (#participation_channels) option is select or deselect. I'm trying to populate second multiselect dropdown(#field_zone) but second dropdown is not populate

[plugin used](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#participation_channels').multiselect({
        onChange: function (option, checked) {
            var channels = $('#participation_channels').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                data: {channels: channels},
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, zone) {
                        $("#field_zone").append('<option value="' + zone.zone + '">' + zone.zone + '</option>');
                    });
                    $("#field_zone").attr('multiple', 'multiple'); 
                   $("#field_zone").multiselect(); 
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('#field_zone').multiselect();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force the multiselect to regenerate all options from the original `select` element. So, after creating the new options for the select (inside the `success` callback) you should change:

```
$("#field_zone").multiselect();
```

to:

```
$("#field_zone").multiselect('rebuild');
```

so the multiselect will be rebuilt based on the updated options.